# DOMException: Could not start audio source

Tags: webspeech-api

I'm writing a React App and I'm using [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) for both speaking and voice recognition. I've written some code that works on desktop Chrome.
The way I ask for permission from the user is the following:

```
 navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(function (stream) {
        console.log('Succeeded');
        /*Handle success*/
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Failed: ', err)
        /*Handle failure*/
  });
```

However, this same code always goes to the catch callback when used from my Android phone, with the following written to the console:

```
Failed: DOMException: Could not start audio source
```

The site asks me if I want to allow microphone usage and when I go into the site settings, it says microphone and sound are both allowed, which makes me believe I've done the user interaction part well.
The site is served over HTTPS (already solved that issue), so I believe this is not an issue as well.

I'm using Xiaomi Mi 9 with Chrome Chrome 86.0.4240.185 in this test.

My first instinct is that I'm doing something wrong here? If this is the case, what?
Otherwise, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Ever solve this? I'm running in to an identical problem.

Comment: @swooby No, gave up, wasn't paramount for the functionality at the time. My conclusion is that this API is not yet fully supported on mobile. Might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6):

Check if your Android app has required permissions:

```
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS (might be optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check html or ejs file ;
you have to use   **in the body tags**

Such as:

```html
<body>
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, and just managed to solve it.

Step 1 : AndroidManifest.xml

Add permissions to RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>
```

Step 2 : MainActivity.java

Grant all access to the webview when asked.
Enable javascript.
Request permission to record audio when launching app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Check and request permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            // Load the web content
            webView.loadUrl("https://....com/");
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, load the web content
                webView.loadUrl("https://....com/");
            } else {
                // Permission denied, show a message to the user or handle as needed
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is concerned with JavaScript from within the Browser.